# Can Solid Snake See via the Codec?

Tags: video-games, technology, metal-gear-solid

In Metal Gear Solid, Solid Snake remarks that he didn't expect a designer of world-class technology to be so cute. How could he notice she was cute if the codec directly stimulates the bones of the inner ear?

Answer (score 10):

He may have been commenting on how cute she sounds. In both the Japanese and English dubs Mei Ling VAs gave her a rather "cutesy" voice. A closer look at the conversation and you'll see he doesn't say she *looks* cute, only that she's cute.

> Mei Ling : What's wrong?
>
> Snake    : Nothing...I just didn't expect a world-class designer of military          technology to be so...cute.

Also, Snake has something of a reputation as a ladies man and was probably playing up the part. A latter conversation with Meryl alludes to this.

> Snake    : It's your eyes.
>
> Meryl    : My eyes?
>
> Snake    : They're not soldiers eyes.
>
> Meryl    : They're rookie's eyes, right?
>
> Snake    : No, they're beautiful compassionate eyes.
>
> Meryl    : Just what I'd expect from the legendary Solid Snake.  You trying to sweep me off my feet?
>
> Snake    : Don't worry.  You'll land back on them once you meet me.  The reality is no match for the legend, I'm afraid.